# Is it possible to create an HTML body on Mail with CSS Hover on it?

Tags: html, css, email

I created an HTML Body Mail.
First i tried in coding in raw html file to create the css effect i want like hover.
It is working on my html test file. But when I used it for HTML Mail Body Its not Working.

Below is the CSS that I used.

```
<style>
.container .btn:hover {
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.05;
    border-radius:50px; 
}
#imgheader{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
.container .btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;

}
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
}
 
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul li:before {
    content: "\2714\0020";
    color: purple;
}

td {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

It works on my HTML Page Sample. but when i apply it on HTML Mail body. It Doesn`t Show what the css supposed to show.

This should be the page output.
It has Check on every table td and hover on image.

Here is the sample Output:

[image]

Comment: Not every CSS rules is supported in every email client. Please check every rule manually in e.g. https://www.caniemail.com/

Comment: E.g. https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=%3Ahover

Comment: CSS isn't supported well at all. You best chance is to use HTML4 techniques with **`inline-style`**